# Python : generate an array of time and append it to the dataframe

Tags: python

I want to generate a column of time in seconds (preferably in datetime format) and append it to my dataframe

e.g. I want to generate the time in seconds from 11:00:00am to 14:59:00pm

```
time
11:00:00
11:00:01
11:00:02
11:00:03
....
```

Comment: Append it in dataframe as a row, or column?

Comment: as a column, thank you for asking

Comment: what did you try up to now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using datetime to create the list, and then create a df to hold it, as you wish.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import pandas as pd

midnight = datetime.combine(datetime.today().date(), time(0))

start = midnight + timedelta(hours=11)
end = midnight + timedelta(hours=15)

lst = [(start + timedelta(seconds=i)).strftime("%X") for i in range((end - start).seconds)]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = lst
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Use %X for format, and you will get list like: ['11:00:00', '11:00:01', '11:00:02' ... ]